# PHP HTML String into CSV

Tags: php, csv, line-breaks

Going around in circles so hopefully someone can put me right.

Generating a CSV through PHP and using my data from MySQL.  Data is inputted by the user via TinyMCE so has various "p" tags etc that I obviously need to strip out which I can do successfully, however the string in the csv still gets displayed in various different cells even after being stripped.

I've tried using strip_tags() and preg matching "/n" and "/r" and all sorts to remove line breaks but no luck as it still appears on new cells.

I'm using a semi colon as the seperator in the csv.

An example of a string i'm trying to strip all html from would be`<p>I would like to join because it looks fun</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>Help me.</p>`.  It only happens when their is more than one

tag or something - if the string is simply one line, it works no issues.

Heres the csv code i'm using:

```
    echo 'Username;Email;Date joined;Reason for joining'."\r\n";

    foreach($users as $user) {
        $csv_data .= $user->username . ';' . $user->email. ';' . date("d/m/y", $user->time_created) . ';' .  $user->reason_for_joining  .';'."\r\n";
    }

    echo $csv_data;
```

Where am i going wrong?

Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSV format has more pitfalls than one might imagine (as you are experiencing). Therefore, don't reinvent the wheel and use [`fputcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php), which correctly escapes everything that needs escaping.

`fputcsv` expects to write to a file, but you can give it a fake file to write to instead, as outlined [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php):

```
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

$delimiter = ';';
$headers = array('Username', 'Email', 'Date joined', 'Reason for joining');
fputcsv($fp, $headers, $delimiter);

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $fields = array($user->...);
    fputcsv($fp, $fields, $delimiter);
}

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Thanks @deceze.  I'm creating the csv file through php this way: header("Content-Type: application/csv");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=users.csv");.  Can i still use fputcsv?

Comment: @thats Please have a look at my update again, I stupidly made the fake file writing more complicated than it needs to be. You can write directly to the output buffer without going through a temporary file.

Comment: Was looking everywhere for this answer. I was beginning to think I'd have to output to a file then use file_get_contents in order to display it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the "\r" for the first echo,
supposed to be:

```
echo 'Username;Email;Date joined;Reason for joining'."\r\n";
```

and better set $csv_data to blank before the 'for' loop.

and if either 'username', 'email', 'reason_for_joining' has the semicolon, 
the code will generate a mal-formed csv.

Comment: and better set $csv_data to blank before the 'for' loop

Comment: and if either 'username', 'email', 'reason_for_joining' has the semicolon, the code will generate a mal-formed csv

Comment: Thanks @nicola - i fixed up my blunders.  Still no luck though and i can confirm no semi colon exists :).

Comment: as i know, there are always many "&nbsp;" in the html generated by TinyMCE, you can see this '&nbsp;' in the example reason-to-join in your question. This '&nbsp;' contains a semicolon. Maybe that's why?

Comment: I tried removing the nbsp; but still no luck.  However @deceze suggestion worked!  Thanks @nicola